# View with TextField or just text

Tags: ember.js

I would like to create a view which should render a textfield if a condition is met or just a text if not.

Is there any good documentation about writing reuseable Views?

**Edit 23.04.2013 - my solution for inplace editing**

I ended up with the following for inplace edits (thanks to Myslik). I will add some more features like "empty" placeholders.

Coffeescript:

```
App.InplaceTextField = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'div'
  isEditing: false
  template: Ember.computed( ->
    return Ember.Handlebars.compile([
      '{{#if view.isEditing}}',
      '{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.content"}}',
      '{{else}}',
      '{{view.content}}',
      '{{/if}}'
    ].join('\n'))
  )
  focusOut: ->
    @get('controller').get('store').commit()
    @set('isEditing', false)
  click: ->
    @set('isEditing', true)
```

Handlebars:

`title` is one attribute of my model which is passed to my views

```
{{view App.InplaceTextField contentBinding="title"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to write a view for it? You could do this in your template:

```
{{#if condition}}
    {{input value=name}}
{{else}}
    {{name}}
{{/if}}
```

**EDIT:**

So you can customize `Ember.TextField` like this:

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['disabled']
});
```

then you can do something like this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="value" disabledBinding="condition"}}
```

Comment: I know it's the easiest (and most messy) way if you have a couple of fields to edit.